# Multiple characters from Mac keyboard

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, macbook, remapping

I have a Macbook Pro and all of a sudden some keys started giving me multiple different letters.  For example, I type `E` and I get `EW`.  Or `2` and I get `23`.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This has (most likely) nothing to do with your keyboard layout, so you need no remapping.

Sounds like you spilled your favorite beverage over your keyboard, to be honest.

Does it appear in all applications, or only some? Could you try opening `Applications > Utilities > Terminal` and look if it happens there?

Try starting the machine from a boot disk (such as the one included with your Mac). Don't reinstall the OS, but open a Terminal (in the menu bar, I think it's under "Utilities") and try typing. Does this issue appear? If not, it's a problem with your installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the trial of controllermate, it should show you if your keyboard is registering multiple keypresses, as it will highlight the keys as you press them. It will also help you to remap the keys if that ends up being the solution.